# Delete button which deletes database row

Tags: php, function

I just made a php function

```
function deletebooking($orderID){

    $sql="DELETE FROM bs_reservations WHERE id='".$orderID."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("oopsy, error when tryin to delete events 2");

}
```

I have a .php file which process a submitted form and then displays a HTML page. How do i add a delete booking button which calls the above function to the HTML page. The $orderID variable is already set.

Suggestions Welcome

Comment: Add `(int)` right before your `$orderID` in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a javascript code on the button which you click to delete the record
as

```
<input type="button" name-"abc" id="abc" onclick="return Deleteqry(<?php echo $orderID ?>);"/>
```

Now you can write the javascript function inside the `<head></head>` as

```
function Deleteqry(id)
{ 
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")==true)
           window.location="yourpagename.php?del="+id;
    return false;
}
```

Now you can write on the top of your page as

```
 if($_GET['del'])
   {
    deletebooking($orderID);

   }
```

Here we are using a message alert for the conformation of the deletion using the javascript alert box...

Comment: Thanks mate, with the if statement am i keeping that in the same file or is that in "yourpage.php"

Comment: yes you can write the if($_GET['del']) code  on the top of yourpagename.php file

Comment: for some reason it does not delete the booking. is there anything wrong with my sql

Comment: First of all check if the ($orderID) is set or not. You can echo the $orderID.  Also make sure that you wrote the function function deletebooking($orderID) on the same page and the <input> type is button not submit.

Comment: what type should the input button be?
I echo'd it but nothing came up, does that mean it hasnt actually been passed?

<?php
 
 include "includes/dbconnect.php";
 include "includes/functions.php";
 
 if($_GET['del'])
   {
   deletebooking($orderID);

   } 
   echo $orderID;
   
?>

Comment: I mean the buton you click to delete the record should be like <input type='button' > don't use <input type='submit'>

Comment: this is what i have 
` <input type="button" value = "Delete Booking" name-"abc" id="abc" onclick="return Deleteqry(<?php echo $orderID ?>);"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Two things.  First, look up "SQL injection."  Sanitize the input of your query.

Second: don't do this.  It's not a good idea.  If the `orderID` is already set on the page, then presumably it can be changed by the user to anything they want and then deleted.  Instead, you should associate the orderID deleting with authentication, or have a status for order IDs instead ("Deleted," for instance) that prevents loss of any data.

Other than that, the other answer will do what you need.  This is not complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example page, let's call it `page.php`:

```
<?
    include "includes/dbconnect.php";
    include "includes/functions.php";

    if ($_POST['delete']){
        deletebooking(intval($_POST['delete']));
        echo "deleted!";
        exit;
    }
?>
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="<?=intval($orderID)?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete order #<?=intval($orderID)?>" />
</form>
```

The one file is both the form that you present to the user and the code that performs the actual deletion. We pass the ID of the record to be deleted as a hidden form value.

Comment: this works fine, but there is one issue, as im new to php. I dont understand what needs to be in "your_page.php" is that just a page it loads up?

Comment: it's the file which contains the your function and the second fragment of code in my post

Comment: unfortunetly it does not actually delete anything.
This is my "your_Page.php"
<?php
 
 include "includes/dbconnect.php";
 include "includes/functions.php";
 
 
  
if ($_POST['delete']){
  deletebooking($orderID);
}  
  
   echo "Deleted"
   
?>

Comment: it sounds like your order id isn't actually getting sent. i'll modify my answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest adding a reload in your function this way the id doesn't stay in the url after the delete action.

```
$page = 'current.php';

if($_GET['del'])
   {
    deletebooking($orderID,$page);

   }  

function deletebooking($orderID,$page){

    $sql="DELETE FROM bs_reservations WHERE id='".$orderID."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("oopsy, error when tryin to delete events 2");
    header('Location: '.$page, true, 303);
}
```