# Delete a database row using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to delete a row in a database when a button is clicked. I've been trying to get it running using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878201/delete-button-which-deletes-database-row).

This is the Delete js function:

```
function Delete(id, classname){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this reference?") == true) {
        window.location="delete"+classname+".php$del="+id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The reason I have a different delete page for each class is because I have a delete() function inside the class function.

Here Is how I am trying to make the label clickable so that the page will be changed:

```
<label class="btn smallbtn" type="submit" id="delete" onclick="return Delete("100086","BookSeries")">-Delete-</label>
```

However, the line of html code is giving me an error of `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token }` whenever I click it.

Apologies in advance as I am not experienced with javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape your quotes or use single quotes: `"return Delete(100086,\"BookSeries\")"`

Comment: Can't believe that's all I was missing. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed single quote.Try with below changes

```
<label class="btn smallbtn" type="submit" id="delete" onclick="return Delete('100086','BookSeries')">-Delete-</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a rookie mistake. :/ Works fine now